# What symmetries arise among $n$ complex numbers on the unit circle if the sum of their squares is zero?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, complex-numbers

> Suppose I had a list of $N$ complex numbers $\{z_i\}$ arrayed on the unit circle. If it is required that this set obeys
>   $$
> \sum_i z_i^2 = 0,
> $$ 
>   what restrictions does this place on the arrangement of the $z_i$ with respect to one another?

There is of course a rotational degree of freedom but I am gravitating toward the idea that the sum of squares being zero restricts the arrangement to one of a high degree of symmetry, relating to the kinds of polygons that can be constructed from $N$ points.

This seems like something that would have been well studied however I am struggling to find any material relating to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just one equation, so not a very high degree of symmetry.  The squares $z_i^2$ form an arrangement of points on the circle whose centre of mass is at $0$.  Given these, each $z_i$ has two possible values opposite each other on the circle.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by possible values on opposite sides of the circle but if I take for example $N$ prime, it's not clear to me that the possible configurations of each point on the unit circle have much freedom. Regular polytopes seem to abound?

Comment: @User71942, I can't believe you wrote that after (presumably) reading my answer! There is no reason at all to expect regular polytopes.

Comment: As @TonyK wrote, you can start with any $N-2$ points on the unit circle, and then pick two more so the sum of squares is $0$.  Opposite on the circle means $z$ and $-z$, which have the same square.

Answer (score 0):

The squaring really adds nothing to the question. You might just as well ask what such a set looks like if $\sum z_i=0$. And you can start with *any* set of $N-2$ numbers, as long as their sum has absolute value less than $2$; then you can pick the last two numbers to bring the sum to $0$. The only way that this can fail is if you are requiring that the numbers are all distinct; then you might find that one of your last two numbers is equal to one of the original $N-2$ numbers. But this is a "probability-zero" case.

Comment: I quite disagree with your first point, the set of points satisfying the sum of squares and the sum of the $z_i$ is different. An immediate example is for $N=2$, with $z_1=1$ and $z_2=-1$.

Comment: @User71942: Yes, but what _kind_ of answer are you hoping for here? The squaring is just a detail, really. What is important is that your "high degree of symmetry" is a pipe dream.